# The sync data between folder on window through cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I have 2 Upload folders on server 192..168.2.3 192.168.2.4, both servers are running windows 2008r2. I want to sync the Upload folder of server 192.168.2.4 with the Upload folder of server 192.168.2.3, I have installed cygwin and use rsync to sync. I write a sync.sh file and a sync.bat file to do the sync. When syncing data in the Upload folder of server 192.168.2.3 located in Upload/./ of server
192.168.2.4. I don't know why the dot is created and the sync data is saved in it.

The content of file sync.sh is:

```
rsync -av administrator@192.168.2.3:/cygdrive/d/Upload/ /cygdrive/d/Upload/
```

The content of file sync.bat is:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l /home/Administrator/sync_upload_adminui.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

A single dot in a directory path, whether that path is seen from Windows or from Cygwin, represents the current directory. The path `Upload/./` is the same as just using `Upload/`